# Server requests / JSON parsing

Tags: android, json

What can you recommend in terms of tools for *requesting* a server and *parsing* received JSON data? Apart from simple parsing, I might want to map those responses to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexjson works on Android for this exact purpose.

http://flexjson.sourceforge.net